# Can i use Docker for creating exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, macos, docker, pyinstaller

I am supposed to create an executable for windows, mac and linux. However, I don't have a windows machine for time being and also I don't have a mac at all. I do have a Linux machine but I don't want to change the partition or even create a dual boot with windows.

I have created an application using python and am making my executable using pyinstaller. If I make use of Docker (install images of windows and mac on linux), will I be able to create executable for windows and mac with all dependencies (like all `.dll` for windows and if any similar for mac)?

Comment: Docker is a Linux process isolation system. You can not run Windows in it. Virtual Box would be able to run a Windows VM. Creating the software package is an other question.

Comment: thanks for the reply @KlausD. Better i will try it with VirtualBox then.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I don't think so. Your docker container container will be a Linux system. If you run it, when ever you are on windows/mac/linux, it is still running on a linux environement so you it will not be a windows or mac compatible binary. I don't know well of python. But if you can't make windows binary from linux, you will not be able to do so in a container.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can.

If you install Wine inside the container, then you can install the Windows version of Python + pyinstaller and build an exe using that. You can even install binary dependencies if you install the standalone visual studio build packages.

A python 2.7 implementation of such a thing can be found at:

- https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller (newer, doesn't support binary packages, haven't used it)
- https://github.com/scottbelden/docker-winpyinstaller (helped to develop this)

Comment: There is a Docker container on Docker Hub already configured for doing exactly what you've described: https://hub.docker.com/r/brimstone/pyinstaller

Comment: Advertisement for my fork of cdrx/docker-pyinstaller: https://github.com/white-gecko/docker-pyinstaller/pkgs/container/docker-pyinstaller (works as of 2021-08)